# Vue no carga componente en los archivos de views

Tags: vue.js, vue3, vite, vue-router

Tengo un proyecto de Vue 3 con Vite. Quise implementar Vue-router, pero, al intentar cargar los componentes a los archivos de views no lo renderiza. Aquí muestro todo de manera más visual.

`router.js`

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import HomeView from "./views/HomeView.vue";
import BookView from "./views/BookView.vue";

const routes = [
    { path: "/", name: "home", component: HomeView },
    { path: "/book", name: "book", component: BookView },
];

const history = createWebHistory();
const router = createRouter({
    history,
    routes,
});

export default router;
```

Y estos son los archivos de `HomeView.vue` y `BookView.vue`:

`HomeView.vue`

```
<script>
    import SearcherInput from "../components/SearcherInput.vue";
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <SearcherInput />
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped></style>
```

`BookView.vue`

```
<script setup></script>

<template>
  <h2>Books</h2>
</template>

<style scoped></style>
```

El contenido HTML se muestra correctamente cuando ingreso a alguna de las rutas e intente verificar si el componente era el que estaba presentando el fallo, así que lo importe directamente en el archivo `App.vue` y este se renderiza correctamente. Viendo la consola me aparece el siguiente warning

```
HomeView.vue:6
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: SearcherInput
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <HomeView onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

Comment: podrías chequear https://router.vuejs.org/guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta registrar el componente.

#### Opción 1 - Registrar Local

En tu archivo `HomeView.vue`:

```
<script>
  import SearcherInput from "../components/SearcherInput.vue";

  export default {
    components: {
      SearcherInput
    }
  }
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <SearcherInput />
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped></style>
```

---

#### Opción 2 - Registrar Global

En tu archivo `index.html`:

```
<div id="app"></div>

<script type="module">
  import { createApp } from 'vue'
  import App from './App.vue'
  import SearcherInput from "./components/SearcherInput.vue";

  const app = createApp(App).mount('#app')
  app.component('SearcherInput', SearcherInput)
</script>
```

---

**Más info:**

- [Vue.js > Guide > Component Registration](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html)

Comment: Gracias. Ya lo importa correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar implementar tu código usando [`vue-auto-routing`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-auto-routing).

```
import HomeView from "./views/HomeView.vue";
import BookView from "./views/BookView.vue";

const routes = [
    { path: "/", name: "home", component: HomeView },
    { path: "/book", name: "book", component: BookView },
  ];
```

Ejemplo:

```
// Import generated routes
import routes from 'vue-auto-routing'

import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  // Pass the generated routes into the routes option
  routes
})
```